# Is it possible to do nested if function in script on googlesheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a very early beginner on google sheets and excel and have a google sheet with pricing information and need an automatic conversion from multiple currencies that i need to go down a full column starting on line 15.

I have been trying to use the if function in a script but it seems like i'm either using the wrong function for the job or my code needs some major tweaking.

---

```
function KWDBuyingPrice() {

      var KWDBuyingTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var WorkingCell = KWDBuyingTotal.getRange("G15").getValue();


      if(WorkingCell="kwd"){
        KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$7");
      }
      if(WorkingCell="usd"){
        KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$8");
      }
      if(WorkingCell="eur"){
        KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$9");
      }
      if(WorkingCell="gpd"){
        KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$10");
      }

      var LastRow = KWDBuyingTotal.getLastRow();
      var FillDownRange = KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4,LastRow-4);
      KWDBuyingTotal.getRange("D15").copyTo(FillDownRange);

}
```

---

Based on my code I expect it to give me the conversion from currency to KWD in another cell but whats happening is that it is giving me the output of my first if function for all the rows even if it doesnt match "gpd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D15:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H15:INDEX(H15:H,COUNTA(H15:H))*SWITCH(G15:INDEX(G15:G,COUNTA(H15:H)),"kwd",$I$7,"usd",$I$8))
```

- [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690) to switch value in Col G according to the currency.
- `INDEX/COUNTA` to getLastRow on the sheet.
- `ARRAYFORMULA` to fill up the whole sheet upto last row using arrays instead of using excel's old drag fill method.

Comment: This is what I was doing (only using a much more complicated formula! so thanks for the input!) but now I need it to copy the formula down anytime a new row is added automatically.. Thanks though!

Comment: @Noura Added a array formula. No need to drag fill.

Comment: can you please explain what you did there? im still very new and didnt understand it..

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly, all i had to do was add the 2 remaining currencies!!!I would still like to learn how to do it using script though if you know how!

Answer (score 1):

You have made a simple mistake. In javascript a single equal sign '=' means assignment and the answer to the if statement will always be true. Instead you need to use '==='.

```
var KWDBuyingTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var WorkingCell = KWDBuyingTotal.getRange("G15").getValue();


if(WorkingCell === "kwd"){
    KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$7");
} else if(WorkingCell === "usd"){
    KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$8");
} else if(WorkingCell === "eur"){
    KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$9");
} else if(WorkingCell === "gpd"){
    KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4).setValue("=H15*$I$10");
}

var LastRow = KWDBuyingTotal.getLastRow();
var FillDownRange = KWDBuyingTotal.getRange(15,4,LastRow-4);
KWDBuyingTotal.getRange("D15").copyTo(FillDownRange);
```

Comment: Also, not necessary to solve your problem but for better code flow, I changed your code to use the if/else structure.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I just tried this but then the cells that should have gotten the new price just went blank, oh just realized the if/else! will try now..

Comment: I plugged in the code you wrote and got nothing in return.. any advice? Ive been struggling with this bit of code for over 2 days now :(

Comment: @NouraZubaid try using `setFormula()` rather than `setValue()` for this function.

Comment: @ross Same problem.. So I have come to realize that my problem is most likely coming from my WorkingCell variable where G15 is not changing to the descending rows when the script is being copied down.

Answer (score 0):

#### Requirement:

Copy formula down a column depending on value in another cell.

---

#### Solution:

Instead of using `range.copyTo()`, run this through a `for` loop and change the cell value based on `i` as we move through the sheet.

---

#### Example:

```
function kwdBuyingPrice() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sh.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 14; i < lastRow - 4; i++) {
    var currency = data[i][6];
    var setRange = sh.getRange(i+1, 4);
    if(currency === 'kwd') {
      setRange.setFormula('=H'+(i)+'*$I$7');
    } else if(currency === 'usd') {
      setRange.setFormula('=H'+(i)+'*$I$8');
    } else if(currency === 'eur') {
      setRange.setFormula('=H'+(i)+'*$I$9');
    } else if(currency === 'gpd') {
      setRange.setFormula('=H'+(i)+'*$I$10');
    }
  }  
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

This script uses a `for` loop to on each row of the sheet to populate the formula in column D based on the result of the `if` statement you already defined in your function. `i` starts at 0 and is incremented by 1 every time the for loop runs, that's why I'm using it in the `setFormula()` for each row. I've incorporated your `lastRow - 4` in the `for` loop to make sure it only runs for the parameters you were already passing to it.

**Note:** Like @CampaignCloner already mentioned, `=` is used for assigning, you should be using `===` for your `if` statements to compare the values.

Comment: thanks! ill try this right away and *try* to understand the explanation! and thank you for the explanation! really appreciate it!

Comment: I just tried it, everything works but its still doing the same thing of returning returning the first if no matter what the value in the cell searched is.

Comment: Is the value in the cell EXACTLY 'kwd', as in all lower case etc? If it's not the exact same it will not find anything, however it shouldn't be returning anything at all...

Comment: yup, exactly.. I have a question though regarding the variable "cell" though, is there any way to make sure that it is moving down with each row?

Comment: Oh! That's what you mean! Yes sure, I've edited the original example to include this.

Comment: basically, it is only checking cell G15 for all rows, I need it to check the G row in general based on what row it is extracting the original value of kwd,usd,eur,gpd not only G15

Comment: Yep I'm with you now, I've moved `var cell` to inside the `for` loop and it should work now.

Comment: now it isnt doing anything at all, hehe! this little bit of script has been driving me crazy for 2 days!

Comment: Apologies, please see script in the answer now, it should work for you. My fault for being lazy with that edit, didn't think it through but after taking some time it's running now.

Comment: `getValue()` and `setFormula()` inside the loop will really slow things. Use arrays instead.

Comment: I've moved the `getValues()` out of the loop but how would you use arrays for the `setFormula()` when it needs to look at every line individually? Would you push a group to an array then set it once you come across the next result?

Comment: @ross thanks for this! it still isnt doing anything though.. The array given to me by TheMaster worked very well though so i guess im just sticking to that.. I have already spent waaay too much time trying to figure this script out.. I had also used scripts for other columns i needed and realized that the array was also faster than the scripts.. Thank you so much for all your help and input though! it is much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah honestly the formula is going to be your best bet for this - even if you could get this script working it would have been slower than the formula @TheMaster provided.

Comment: @ross yes. Just like setValues(), you create a new output array of formulas and batch ``setFormulas()``. Also, `switch()`  would be a better call in js too instead of multiple if else's